# Are my boundary conditions in my stiffness matrix correct?

Tags: finite-element, numerics

I am trying to find a P1 Lagrange finite element solution to the following ODE:

$\begin{cases}-u''+u'+u=f~~~~~~~~\text{in}~~(0,1)\\ u(0)=1, u'(1)=0\end{cases}$

Where $f(x)=-2e^{x}+2\left(1-x\right)e^{x}+\left(1-x\right)^{2}e^{x}$.

---

**My procedure:**

First I obtained the variational formula $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}U_ia(\phi_i,\phi_j)=<f,\phi_j>$ where each $\phi_i$ is a hat function and $a(u,v)=\int_0^1u'v'+u'v+uv$, then solve our ODE is equivalent to solve $AU=b$ where $A=[a(\phi_i,\phi_j)]$, $U=[U_i]$ and $b=[<f,\phi_i>]$.

My next step is take $A(1,:)=[1,0,0,...,0]$, $A(n,:)=[0,0,...,1,1]$ and $b(1)= 1, b(n)=0$ to ensure that the solution meets the initial conditions (Is it correct?).

If I had my initial conditions correct I would not understand what my problem is since I checked in my code my matrix $A$ and vector $b$ and they are correct and yet I get an incorrect solution.

Comment: Why would you set $A(n,:)$ to $[0,0,\ldots,1,1]$ instead of $[0,0,\ldots,0,1]$?

Comment: Is this an initial value or a boundary value problem? If it is an initial value problem both conditions should be specified on $x=0$ or $x=1$, and if it is a boundary value problem, the value of $u$ and $u'$ should be specified at both $x=0,1$ boundaries.